# Is there any way to use jQuery's deferred / promise / when / then features for multiple ajax calls in a loop?

Tags: jquery, loops, jquery-deferred, promise

I've been reading how the newer jQuery features `Deferred` / `promise` / `when` / `then` can be used to simplify acting on multiple asynchronous events such as AJAX queries.

But all of the examples I've been reading talk about a set number of queries that are known in advance.

```
$.when($.ajax("/page1.php"), $.ajax("/page2.php")).then(myFunc, myFailure);
```

<sup>(Borrowed from [Coding Freak's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6368444/527702))</sup>

What about when you don't know them in advance, such as calling the same paged web API in a loop with different parameters, such as some features of the MediaWiki and StackExchange APIs have - is there any way to make use of these newer jQuery features in this case or do we have to go back to the old way?

Comment: Have a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647527/jquery-deferred-do-i-need-pipes-or-chains-to-achieve-this-pattern/6648219#6648219

Comment: Or this question / answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785724/queue-ajax-requests-using-jquery-queue

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery $.when() with variable arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011652/jquery-when-with-variable-arguments)

Answer (score -3):

You can call a function like ajaxloop('/page1.php')

```
function ajaxloop(url)
{
    $.ajax({
            url:url,
            success:function()
                       {
                     if(url=='/page1.php')
                      {
                       ajaxloop('/page2.php')
                      }
                     else
                     {
                      ajaxloop('/page1.php')
                       }
                 }
     });
}
```

Comment: give me specific question you are trying to looping your jquery or not.

Comment: It looks like you need to know the exact number of iterations ahead of time and include inline code for those exact iterations.